# Is there some way to change the minute of the hour TimeMachine backs up?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I have 2 Macs, both running macOS Big Sur 11.6.4 backing up at exactly the same time (33th minute of every hour).

Is there some way to change the minute of the hour TimeMachine backs up?

With both machines at the same time it causes my Synology NAS to slow down too much as it cannot seem to handle many users at once.

If one of them starts at the first minute past every hour and the other one fifteen minutes later there would be no problem. But you cannot change this in the settings window. Disabling and re-enabling TimeMachine at a later time doesn't change it.

Utilities like [TimeMachineEditor](https://tclementdev.com/timemachineeditor/) also don't work, because I just want to change the minutes and use regular TimeMachine. I'm sure there must be a plist file somewhere I can edit.

Any thoughts?

Comment: “…because I just want to change the minutes and use regular TimeMachine.” All TimeMachineEditor does is edit the Time Machine settings for you. It is not a replacement for Time Machine. It actually does exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

The TimeMachineEditor website says:

> TimeMachineEditor starts backups in Time Machine when it is most appropriate, the whole backup process is still handled by Time Machine. TimeMachineEditor does not make changes to your system, it simply runs as an alternative scheduler to start your backups. Therefore it is safe and easy to use.

I’ve used tools like that in the past, and I believe that statement. Also, I’ve found poor Mac performance letting Time Machine run every hour, especially now that iCloud backs up most of my files, so I recommend using a tool like that that does limit when your Time Machine backups run.